# how to display question one at the time from database with flutter?

Tags: mysql, database, flutter

i am new to the flutter

i want to display the questions that i get from my database, currently i can show the first question with index but i can't go to next question.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE4Dp.png)

here the code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  int index = 0;

  return  Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: new Text("Huruf"),
        ),

        body: FutureBuilder<List<DataHiragana>>(
    future: fetchhhiragana(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      if (snapshot.hasData){
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal:100),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
                    Text("${snapshot.data[index].huruf}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80,),),
                    SizedBox(height: 30,),
                    new TextField(
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40,  ),
                      
                    onSubmitted: (answer) {
                        if (answer.contains("${snapshot.data[index].ejaan}")){
                           debugPrint("The answer is correct");
                           setState (() {
                               index= index+1;   
                 
                           });
                        }else{
                           debugPrint("The answer is incorrect");
                        }
                        }
                      ),
                      
    ],
          ),
          );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('error');
      }
        return Text('loading..');
    },
    ),
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `int index = 0;` is placed inside the build method, but you try to increment the index in the `setstate((){});`.
This is not possible, because `setState((){});` reruns the build method, which sets index to 0 every time, rendering your incrementation useless.

A possible fix would be moving `int index = 0;` above the build method.

Comment: You're welcome :)
Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.